# How do we edit the default Title text shown when asking a question in magento.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Right now the default text in Magento StackExchange reads poorly:

> What's your the Magento e-Commerce platform question? Be specific.

How can this be edited?

[image: Default Question Title Text]

Comment: Can you post a link or screen shot?

Comment: Just edited post with picture

Comment: @pops can maybe help here. None of us site mods can.

Comment: Sounds like they need to give you a bigger hammer

Comment: Any traction on this?  It's three weeks old today--although I did post during the holidays.

Comment: I think I did a bad job following up with the SE team. I've checked in again & set a reminder. At this point, keep the blame for delay pointed at me :-)

Comment: In an unrelated note, I wonder how many eyes have seen this without noticing...

Comment: Too many, that's how many.  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good point! Now it says

> What's your Magento question? Be specific.

To answer the question you actually asked, this is a setting that can be changed only by someone with dev access. It's an easy change, you just need to get the right person's attention. That's hard to do directly, so your best bet is to post on meta and wait for a CM like me to see it... and possibly bug your mods about it and have them poke me if I get distracted thinking about Winter Bash and drop the ball on responding to meta... not that that would ever happen....

Comment: Not exactly an "Answer" to my exact question but I'll take it.  (I guess the technical answer was "tell Pops to change it")

Comment: Fair enough, updated!